# dc.js - multiple lineChart based on separate categories in single csv file

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart, dc.js, crossfilter

For example if I have the following csv file:

`category, number, total
A,1,3
A,2,5
A,3,1
B,1,4
B,2,6
B,3,1
C,1,5
C,2,2
C,3,4`

I was able to follow the following example and separate out the data into different csv files and composing each one.

[github link](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/examples/composite.html)

However, I was wondering how would I recreate the same lineCharts if I were to only have a single csv file and separate each lineChart by each grouped category.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

@minikomi's answer is the straight d3 way to do this.

The dc.js/crossfilter way to do this (if you want your charts to reduce values for each key and interact/filter with other dc charts) is to reduce multiple values in a single group like this:

```
var group = dimension.group().reduce(
    function(p, v) { // add
        p[v.type] = (p[v.type] || 0) + v.value;
        return p;
    },
    function(p, v) { // remove
        p[v.type] -= v.value;
        return p;
    },
    function() { // initial
        return {};
});
```

https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#rows-contain-a-single-value-but-a-different-value-per-row

Then you can specify each line chart by passing the group along with an accessor to the `.group` method like so:

```
lineChartA.group(group, 'A', function(a) { return x.A; })
lineChartB.group(group, 'B', function(a) { return x.B; })
```

If you want to combine the line charts in a single chart, you can compose them with the [composite chart](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md%23composite-chart) or [series chart](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md%23series-chart)

Answer (score 0):

You can [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the data to give 3 different arrays, each which only contain data from each category:

```
var grouped = data.reduce(function(o,d) {
  if(o[d.category]) {
    o[d.category].push(d);
  } else {
    o[d.category] = [d];
  }
  return o;
}, {});
```

Usually in d3 we work with arrays of data, so I'd use [d3.map](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_map) to convert it to an array of pairs key / value

```
var lineData = d3.map(grouped).entries()
```

Now, you can use this to create your lines (leaving out creating scales `x` and `y`), `svg` element etc.:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
             .x(function(d){return x(d.number)})
             .y(function(d){return y(d.total)})

var linesGroup = svg.append("g")

var lines = linesGroup.data(lineData).enter()
                      .append("line")
                      .attr("d", function(d){return line(d.value)})
```

You could also set the stroke color using the `d.key` for the d3.map entries (which will come from the key we used in the reduce step - the category). Don't forget to convert your csv data to numbers too using `parseInt()`.