# Dc.js: Creating a multi-line row chart by grouping values from a selected column

Tags: javascript, multiline, dc.js, composite

I have json data which looks like this

```
{"Iteration": 1, "operation": "boot_server", "response_time": 23.1,
 "Iteration": 1, "operation": "stop_server", "response_time": 5.2,
 "Iteration": 2, "operation": "boot_server", "response_time": 20.1,
 "Iteration": 2, "operation": "stop_server", "response_time": 4.2,
 "Iteration": 3, "operation": "boot_server", "response_time": 30.1,
 "Iteration": 3, "operation": "stop_server", "response_time": 6.2}
```

I want to plot a composite chart with one line chart for each operation type(boot_server, stop_server) with x-axis as Iteration and y-axis as response_time.  The list of operations is not constant and it can vary depending upon the type of test.

I have searched and tried a couple of examples

[dc.js - multiple lineChart based on separate categories in single csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849643/dc-js-multiple-linechart-based-on-separate-categories-in-single-csv-file)
http://bl.ocks.org/jsundram/6728956

but i am not able to make it work for my data. I have just started working on dc.js and know to generate basic charts. Can anyone explain how should i approach this?

Comment: Please take a look at the series chart example: http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/series.html - it's maybe not a perfect design but it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/jsundram/6728956 doesn't work.

I've created a [working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/moshequ/yf2u71cr/): https://jsfiddle.net/moshequ/yf2u71cr/